# Can I get this Python code snippet translated for usage with Axios+Vue?

Tags: python, vue.js, axios, python-requests, translate

The code snippet is simply about performing a post request to a machine learning model endpoint and logging out the response if successful.

```
import urllib.request
import json
import os
import ssl

def allowSelfSignedHttps(allowed):
    # bypass the server certificate verification on client side
    if allowed and not os.environ.get('PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY', '') and getattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context', None):
        ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

allowSelfSignedHttps(True) # this line is needed if you use self-signed certificate in your scoring service.

# Request data goes here
# The example below assumes JSON formatting which may be updated
# depending on the format your endpoint expects.
# More information can be found here:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-advanced-entry-script
data =  {
  "Inputs": {
    "data": [
      {
        "test_date": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "cough": false,
        "fever": 0,
        "sore_throat": false,
        "shortness_of_breath": 0,
        "head_ache": 0,
        "age_60_and_above": "example_value",
        "gender": "example_value"
      }
    ]
  },
  "GlobalParameters": {
    "method": "predict"
  }
}

body = str.encode(json.dumps(data))

url = 'http://8daf0a82-3a30-4581-96c3-5d4374473502.southafricanorth.azurecontainer.io/score'
api_key = '' # Replace this with the API key for the web service

# The azureml-model-deployment header will force the request to go to a specific deployment.
# Remove this header to have the request observe the endpoint traffic rules
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':('Bearer '+ api_key)}

req = urllib.request.Request(url, body, headers)

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    result = response.read()
    print(result)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
    print("The request failed with status code: " + str(error.code))

    # Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
    print(error.info())
    print(error.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore'))
```

I have tried this, but I keep getting

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://8daf0a82-3a30-4581-96c3-5d4374473502.southafricanorth.azurecontainer.io/score. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)."

```
function predict() {
  axios
    .post(
      "http://8daf0a82-3a30-4581-96c3-5d4374473502.southafricanorth.azurecontainer.io/score",
      {
        Inputs: {
          data: [
            {
              cough: S1Val.value,
              fever: S2Val.value,
              sore_throat: S3Val.value,
              shortness_of_breath: S4Val.value,
              head_ache: S5Val.value,
              age_60_and_above: a1.value,
              gender: a2.value,
            },
          ],
        },
        GlobalParameters: {
          method: "predict",
        },
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Orgin": "*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Also note that this endpoint doesn't require any authentication that's why I didn't append an API key to the Bearer when performing the request.

Comment: this looks like C#?!

Comment: I just edited it with the python code, I initially made a mistake